# Can we create embed code without having power bi pro licencse?

Tags: powerbi

I have created report in power bi but i am not able to share it client as i dont have power bi pro license, whenever i clicked on publish to web button it is showing 'Contact your admin to enable embed code creation' pop up message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a share to web without having a Power BI Pro license, however it is turned off by default in the Power BI tenant settings.
[image: Power BI Tenant Settings]

This will need to be enabled by your O365 or Power BI Admin. Please note, this method of sharing is NOT secure, anyone with the url will be able to access or see the report. The URL it generates is publicly accessible. To securely share you will need Power BI Pro, and share via workspaces or apps

Comment: hi @Jon, thanks for your reply, actually we are trying to share reports from our admin account itself, but still we are unable to see tenant settings option. is there any other way to share bi reports.

Comment: To Share externally you can share it, but they will need a Power BI license. Internally you'll need your consumers who you share to have a Pro license.